# Facebook SSO integration, logout method doesn't actually log me out from the Native FB application

Tags: android, single-sign-on, facebook-android-sdk

I have implemented `SSO` for facebook and the login works for FB(native app) when i Login from My App.(third party) , now the issue (or i am not sure if this is restricted by FB) is that when i perform the logOut from My app(third party again) it doesn't log me out of Facebook.

Throw some light on this, if anyone has had the same experience in doing so.

Comment: Yeah, it's just discarding the auth credentials for the user & your app. That would be pretty irritating (and a security issue) if apps could arbitrarily log me out of MY Facebook app.

Comment: would totally agree to you on that one, and so i guess i should consider that it obviously wont be allowed to make a user logout from FB app programmatically.

Comment: would you please mind making that as an Answer so that i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would accept the answer given by `Krylez` , that it isn't possible to log out the user from the Native Facebook Application pro-grammatically.